# How do I get dice to re-roll until it hits the "point" (craps) using a while loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a craps game in which if the computer automatically a pair of dice and if the cpu rolls a 7 or 11 the user win. However if the user rolls a 2, 3, or 12 they automatically lose. And if the user rolls any other number (4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10) that is there "point" and they are to try to roll that point again. (unless they roll a 7 then they lose.) I am trying to get my while loop to continue rolling if the computer rolls a number other than 7 or the "point" but the while loop continues to exit out and will only roll a maximum of two times, and it will continue looping the second value of the roll.

this is what i have now..

```
    int d1 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    int d2 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    int roll = (d1 + d2);
   int point = roll;

System.out.println("The sum for the two dice rolls is " + roll);



while(roll != 7 || roll != point )
{
    System.out.print("reroll");
    int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);


}
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: Sounds to me like you didn't seed random or you are seeding it inside the loop. Try seeding random outside loop

Answer (score 0):

while(roll != 7 || roll != point )

It doesn't make sense to me that it's "||".
Shouldn't it be "&&"?

The way it is right now, the loop will only exit when point==7

Comment: you need roll = d3+d4; in the while loop

Comment: it doesnt appear to print anything

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 you assign the value of roll to point:

```
int point = roll;
```

There is no use to check if "roll != point" in the while-header, because those values never get updated inside the while-loop. They are always equal!
The while-loop will continue forever, once roll gets assigned a value unequal to 7 before the while-loop.